# Why string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\0") is false

Tags: .net, string, c#-4.0

I faced a problem where invisible character `\0` which is pretty like a 'white space' not considered as white space by the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace method. I wonder why this implemented in .NET in so manner and is there any alternative to string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace which can properly handle null-terminate character?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Null is not whitespace.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: '\0' is not white-space

Comment: Are you decrypting something? Often I see the `\0` with badly padded decrypted strings...

Comment: No, it is the last line of CSV file written by the same application. Not sure why this happened but want to make application to read even such 'not ideal' files.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[U+0000](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm) isn't whitespace, basically. `char.IsWhitespace('\0')` returns false, it's not listed as whitespace...

The *null* part of `IsNullOrWhitespace` refers to the string reference itself - not the contents, if that's what you were thinking of.

Note that strings in .NET aren't logically "null-terminated" within managed code, although in practice at the CLR level they are, for interop purposes. (The string knows its own length, but in order to make it easier to work with native code which *does* expect a null terminator, the CLR ensures that there's always a U+0000 after the content of the string.) If you end up with a string containing `\0` you should probably fix whatever produced it to start with.

Comment: *Note that strings in .NET aren't "null-terminated"* This sentence is a little false... As much as the NUL termination in C is present but invisible (`strlen` doesn't count it, `printf("%s", str)` doesn't print it,...), in C# it is the same (`string` are NUL terminated to make easy the interop, but this thing is invisible)

Comment: @xanatos: True, will fix.

Comment: /0 is whitespace for user as it can't be represented as any visible character but takes the place. So I thought string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace should also consider it as whitespace. From your description I understand that '/0' should not normally appear in .NET strings and probably because of this .NET programmers not included it into the list of whitespace characters. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Shoar: No, that's not the definition of whitespace. It's the definition of "unprintable character" perhaps, but that's not the same as whitespace. It's not a matter of what .NET has decided - it's a matter of Unicode categories.

Answer (score 5):

You could replace all `\0` characters with the space character, and then check for whitespace.

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\0".Replace('\0', ' ');
```

Comment: Well, if you're going that way, using `IndexOf` would be simpler and faster.

Comment: Hmm, right, you need to know if *all* the characters are whitespace or `\0`... in that case, `.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || c == '\0')`. Still faster than a replace, and you avoid a lot of iteration (and copying) for typical strings.

Comment: It depends on the length of the string, your solution works better for longer strings, but the replace method is faster for smaller strings. (Just tested it)

Comment: That's pretty unlikely - the internal implementation of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is just a simple C# for loop. Maybe it's just the overhead of LINQ? In that case, you could simply use a for loop yourself. I used LINQ for readability.

Comment: It is probably the overhead of LINQ, I suppose a for loop would be just as fast as the .NET implementation.

Answer (score 4):

For fun historical reasons (they are surely fun, but I wasn't able to find them), `null` has two meanings... The `null` pointer/reference (called `NULL` in C), and the `NUL` (or `NULL`) `\0` character.

[`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) does:

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

with `null` meaning the "`null` reference", empty meaning empty and white-space meaning

> White-space characters are defined by the Unicode standard. The `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method interprets any character that returns a value of true when it is passed to the `Char.IsWhiteSpace` method as a white-space character.

The list of characters that [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t809ektx.aspx) considers a space is present in the page of `Char.IsWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 2):

'\0' character is not considered white space. See [`Char.IsWhitespace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the list of characters that are considered white space.

Use [`Enumerable.All()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you have your own requirements, or even just to add a few chars of your own. Something like this:

```
bool IsMyKindOfWhiteSpace(string input)
{
    char[] more = new char[] { <here goes your list of additional white space chars> };

    return input.All(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x) || more.Contains(x));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension method which adds the null char as a check.

```
public bool IsNullOrWhitespaceOrHasNullChar(this string text)
{
   return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || Regex.IsMatch(text, "\0");
}
```

Note it the null char exists anywhere in the string, it will be found and reported as such, so a string with "a\0" would return true. If that is a concern create a test which checks for a full string of `\0`.

Comment: Using Regex is probably excessive for such simple task especially [in terms of performance](http://theburningmonk.com/2012/05/performance-test-string-contains-vs-string-indexof-vs-regex-ismatch/).

Answer (score 0):

NULL string IS NOT the same as an empty string or white space